# Use AWS CloudWatch Math Expression Metric in Terraform aws_appautoscaling_policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, math, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

I have created a math expression metric in CloudWatch as described [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html).

Now I would like to use this metric in a terraform aws_appautoscaling_policy, as in the example below.
Is this possible?

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "dynamodb_table_read_target" {
  max_capacity       = 100
  min_capacity       = 5
  resource_id        = "table/tableName"
  scalable_dimension = "dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits"
  service_namespace  = "dynamodb"
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "dynamodb_table_read_policy" {
  name               = "DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization:${aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.resource_id}"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "***Use_The_Above_Defined_Metric_Here***"
    }

    target_value = 70
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no resource definition given for this custom metric. Where did you create it? In AWS console?

Comment: Yes, in the console, as described in the link above.

Comment: Were you able to go through @nveo? I'm looking for the same usecase.